# Create and Access Array in One Line with Bash

Tags: bash

If I type the following command I create an array variable.

`A=($(ls | sort))`

Which can be printed by index by doing the following.

`echo ${A[0]}`

Is there any way to do both in one line? The following gives a "bad substitution" error.

`echo ${($(ls | sort))[0]}`

That command seems logical because it is a copy and paste of what was in the variable to where it is used. What is the issue and how can I fix it in one line without defining a variable?

Comment: A variable expression like `${something}` expects the name of a variable. You're not giving it one.

Comment: Shell expansions like this are generally not recursive -- that is, you can't nest one inside the other. You need to do each one separately. (Note: there are some exceptions, but they are just that: *exceptions*.)

Comment: Is there a way to achieve my goal without using recursive expansions?

Comment: You might like using `zsh` more. `print *[0]`. (The output of the glob is already sorted by name, by default.)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ A=($(ls | sort)) && echo ${A[0]}
```